# What does this CSS pathname means?

Tags: css

I saw this CSS pathname on one project I am working on and since I don't understand CSS much, I don't understand what it actually means. The CSS looks like that:

```
body input.name_of_class {
    /*some properties here*/
}
```

What does the `body input` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means all `<input>` tags inside the `<body>` with the class name `name_of_class` will be affected

Comment: Does the `body` need to be there though?

Comment: OK. Thanks. It confused me greatly.

Comment: @KarelBílek No, it's unlikely that a `<input>` element exist outside `<body>`.

Comment: In this selector, no, the body appears to be extraneous. But that is not to say this is always the case. Often, prefixing selectors with the body is a means of limiting styles to certain pages, if your body has an ID, say, e.g. `body#homepage a.sort_link_style` vs. `body#products a.some_link_style`.

Comment: In that case Utkanos, `#homepage a.sort_link_style` would work perfectly fine, if you are working with valid HTML, you never need to use the body tag before another selector, as all elements "should" be inside the body anyway

Comment: @KarelBílek So now you aren't confused but just incorrectly informed.... Wrong answer accepted -.-'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know these selectors you also could google for `cheat sheet`.

[What i found about CSS2](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/css2/)

[What i found about CSS3](http://hyper-text.org/dl/css3_selectors_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `CSS` you see is trying to apply some styles on some `input` elements who have a class **someClass** and they are within the body.

So

```
body input
{
/*some style*/
}
```

may apply these styles to all `input` elements on the page.

So to narrow down your selection , you can use

```
body input.someClass
{
/*some style*/
}
```

This will apply styles to all input element with class **someClass**.